# Passing custom props to a styled-components createGlobalStyle component in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, styled-components

I'm using styled-components with TypeScript to create a GlobalStyle component. I want to pass a custom prop called cssContent to the GlobalStyle component, but I'm encountering a type error.

```
interface GlobalStyleProps {
  cssContent: string;
}

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle<GlobalStyleProps>`
${(props) => props.cssContent}
`;
```

I have a function to generate the cssContent string. In Fact, there are some arguments in this function. This function is needed.

```
export const generateGlobalStyle = (): string => {
  return `
      :root {
      }
//my css code...
    `;
};
```

Pass cssContent as props:

```
function App() {
  const cssContent = generateGlobalStyle();
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyle cssContent={cssContent} />
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

error:

```
Type '{ cssContent: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<ThemedGlobalStyledClassProps<GlobalStyleProps, DefaultTheme>, any, any>> & Readonly<...>'.
```

How can I resolve this type error and pass the custom cssContent prop to my GlobalStyle component?
Thank you.